# How to add a regression line to a scatter plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, regression

I am trying to add a regression line onto a plot in MATLAB.
this is the code I have:

```
errorbar(x,y,SEM,'o')
hold on % Retains current plot while adding to it
scatter(x,y)
title('The Effect of Distance Between Images on the Flashed Face         Distortion Effect','FontSize',14); % Adds title
xlabel('Distance (Pixels)','FontSize',12); % Adds label on the x axis
ylabel('Average Distortion Rating','FontSize',12); % Adds label on the y axis
hold off
```

And this is my code for a regression:
    mdl = fitlm(x,y,'linear');

Could anyone tell me how to combine the two so i get the regression line on the plot?
I am using psychtoolbox on MATLAB on Windows.
Thanks!

Comment: so you also have the Curve Fitting Toolbox I guess? You can simply add `plot(mdl)` with the right axis limits before `hold off` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Before the `hold off` statement, add the following lines:

```
xf = [min(x), max(x)];
plot(xf, polyval(polyfit(x,y,1), xf));
```

You may want to decorate your `plot` call with supplemental arguments setting the line style, and no additional toolboxes are required.